# My media query does not work well and i do not know what i did wrong. It worked sometime ago but not anymore

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My media query does not work well  and i do not know what i did wrong. It worked sometime ago but not anymore. I am targeting larger screen sizes (1920 x 1080), (1680 x 1080) but some how it works for certain pages but not on others. I am confused as to what to do. It only renders for @media (min-width: 768px) and i do not know what to do. Here is the code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    /* for about page */
  .team-back1 {
    height: 690px;
    background-position: 10% center;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    margin-top: 2%;
  }  

    /* for service page */
  .team-back {
    height: 690px;
    background-position: center 20%;
  }

  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.333333%;
    margin-top: -1%;
  }

  div.bhoechie-tab-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 69%;
  }


    /* for home page */

  #home-2 .container-fluid {
    height: 690px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 650px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }   

    /*for project page */
  .pc {
    height: 550px;
    float: right;
  }

  .team-back3 {
    height: 690px;
    background-position: center 20%;
  }

    /* width: 73%; */
  margin-top: 0%;
} 

    /* for contact page */
    /*#contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;}       

    .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 580px !important;}

    #map { 
    height: 580px;}

    .contct-middle-back { 
    height: 580px;}

    .contct-right-back {
    height: 580px; }*/

    /*.row {
    margin-top: 3.5%; }*/

    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
    /* for about page */
  .team-right-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .team-back1 {
    height: 798px;
    background-position: 10% center;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

    /* for service page */
  .team-back {
    height: 798px;
    background-position: center -35%;
  }

  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 60.333333%;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }

  div.bhoechie-tab-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 76%;
  }


    /* for home page */

  #home-2 .container-fluid {
    height: 798px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 680px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }   

    /*for project page */
  .pc {
    height: 580px;
    float: right;
  }

  .team-back3 {
    height: 798px;
    background-position: center -35%;
  }


    /* for contact page */
  #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 798px;
  }

  .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 680px !important;
  }

  #map {
    height: 680px;
  }

  .contct-middle-back {
    height: 680px;
  }

  .contct-right-back {
    height: 680px;
  }

  .row {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
  .team-right-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

    /* for projects*/
  .team-back3 {
    height: 760px;
    background-position: 30% center;
  }

  .project-content {
    height: 512px;
  }

  .bret {
    width: 970px;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  .project-height {
    height: 512px;
    margin-top: -4%;
  }


    /* for about page */
  .team-back1 {
    height: 760px;
    background-position: 10% 20%;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    margin-top: -4%;
  } 

    /* for service page */
  .team-back {
    height: 760px;
    /* background-position: center -40%;   */
    background-position: 5% -10%;
  }

  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 60.333333%;
    margin-top: 4%;
  }

  div.bhoechie-tab-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 89%;
  }


    /* for home page */

  #home-2 .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 700px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }   

    /*for project page */
  .pc {
    /* height: 600px; */
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* float: right;}  */
    /* for contact page */
    #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;
  }

  #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;
  }

  .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 685px !important;
  }

  #map {
    height: 685px;
  }

  .contct-right-back {
    height: 685px;
  }

  .row {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }

  .contt {
    height: 760px!important;
  }
}

    }

@media only screen and (max-width:1140px) {
  #blog-1 .col-sm-4 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
  .top-cart {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-menu ul {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  #team .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }

  #team .col-sm-7 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .single-left {
    width: 100%!important;
  }

  .single-left .reply-form-left-col {
    width: 100%!important;
  }

  .single-right {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .cell-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .cell-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:840px) {
  .footer-left {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }

  .footer-left p {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .footer-right {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #blog-1 .col-sm-4 {
    width: 80%;
  }

  #blog-1 .row {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .left-15 {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }

  #contact-us .col-sm-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {

  .bou {
    height: 620px;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .morphsearch {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile-drop {
    display: block;
  }

  .extra {
    top: 18px!important;
  }

  #blog-1 .col-sm-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #blog-1 .row {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #blog-single-1 .single-post-detail-image img {
    min-width: 100%;
  }

  #blog-single-1 .blog-item {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .home-bottom {
    font-size: 8px!important;
    padding: 7px 12px!important;
  }

  .btn-group-lg>.btn,
    .btn-lg {
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    margin-right: -80px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
  }

  .btn-group-md>.btn,
    .btn-md {
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
    display: none;
  }

  #team .container-fluid {
    padding: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
  }

  .team-back {
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .team-back1 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .abouty {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    padding: 20px 25px 20px 10px;
  }

  .project-content {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .pc {
    padding-left: 70px;
  }

  .serve {
    display: none !important;
  }
    /*.meetus {
        visibility: hidden;
    }*/
  .bighead {
    display: none;
  }

  .bighead2 {
    display: none;
  }

  .righty {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .home-bottom {
    font-size: 5px!important;
    padding: 7px 12px!important;
  }

  .team-right-content .member-content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .team-right-content .member-content img {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .footer-left p {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:580px) {
  .cell-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .home-2-icon {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 250px;
  }

  .cell-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .home3-content-container {
    top: 40px;
  }

  [class*="cell-3"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 250px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .about2-left {
    padding: 21px 20px;
  }

  .about-two-link {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:420px) {
  .left-post-content {
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .left-post-back {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .right-post-content {
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .right-post-image {
    float: left;
  }

  .right-post-back {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:220px) and (max-width:480px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width:767px) {
  .mobile-modal {
    display: none;
  }

  .mob-head {
    display: none;
  }

  .mob-subhead {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 33.666667%;
  }
    /*.col-sm-7 {
        width: 67.333333%;
    } */
  .bouts {
    width: 58%;
  }

  .bret {
    width: 750px;
  }

  .pc {
    height: 490px;
  }

  .row {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }

  .team-back1 {
    height: 548px;
  }

  .team-back {
    height: 548px;
  }

  .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 548px!important;
  }

  .contct-middle-back {
    height: 548px;
  }

  .contct-right-back {
    height: 548px;
  }

  #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 548px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cmine {
    width: 1024px;
  }
}
```

Probably i am not placing the media query code in accordance or something. I just need an insight. Here is the website link of the actual page [CLICK TO OPEN](http://placmedia.com/dt)

Comment: validate your css here https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input ...you will find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the ordering of your media query css. so why don't you try to order them like below. So your code becomes more user friendly as well:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:420px) {
  .left-post-content {
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .left-post-back {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .right-post-content {
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .right-post-image {
    float: left;
  }

  .right-post-back {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .about2-left {
    padding: 21px 20px;
  }

  .about-two-link {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:580px) {
  .cell-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .home-2-icon {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 250px;
  }

  .cell-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .home3-content-container {
    top: 40px;
  }

  [class*="cell-3"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 250px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .home-bottom {
    font-size: 5px!important;
    padding: 7px 12px!important;
  }

  .team-right-content .member-content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .team-right-content .member-content img {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .footer-left p {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {

  .bou {
    height: 620px;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .morphsearch {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile-drop {
    display: block;
  }

  .extra {
    top: 18px!important;
  }

  #blog-1 .col-sm-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #blog-1 .row {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #blog-single-1 .single-post-detail-image img {
    min-width: 100%;
  }

  #blog-single-1 .blog-item {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .home-bottom {
    font-size: 8px!important;
    padding: 7px 12px!important;
  }

  .btn-group-lg>.btn,
    .btn-lg {
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    margin-right: -80px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
  }

  .btn-group-md>.btn,
    .btn-md {
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
    display: none;
  }

  #team .container-fluid {
    padding: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
  }

  .team-back {
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .team-back1 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .abouty {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    padding: 20px 25px 20px 10px;
  }

  .project-content {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .pc {
    padding-left: 70px;
  }

  .serve {
    display: none !important;
  }
    /*.meetus {
        visibility: hidden;
    }*/
  .bighead {
    display: none;
  }

  .bighead2 {
    display: none;
  }

  .righty {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:767px) {
  .mobile-modal {
    display: none;
  }

  .mob-head {
    display: none;
  }

  .mob-subhead {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 33.666667%;
  }
    /*.col-sm-7 {
        width: 67.333333%;
    } */
  .bouts {
    width: 58%;
  }

  .bret {
    width: 750px;
  }

  .pc {
    height: 490px;
  }

  .row {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }

  .team-back1 {
    height: 548px;
  }

  .team-back {
    height: 548px;
  }

  .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 548px!important;
  }

  .contct-middle-back {
    height: 548px;
  }

  .contct-right-back {
    height: 548px;
  }

  #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 548px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:840px) {
  .footer-left {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }

  .footer-left p {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .footer-right {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #blog-1 .col-sm-4 {
    width: 80%;
  }

  #blog-1 .row {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .left-15 {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }

  #contact-us .col-sm-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
  .top-cart {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-menu ul {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  #team .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }

  #team .col-sm-7 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .single-left {
    width: 100%!important;
  }

  .single-left .reply-form-left-col {
    width: 100%!important;
  }

  .single-right {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .cell-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .cell-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1140px) {
  #blog-1 .col-sm-4 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none!important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cmine {
    width: 1024px;
  }
}




@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    /* for about page */
  .team-back1 {
    height: 690px;
    background-position: 10% center;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    margin-top: 2%;
  }  

    /* for service page */
  .team-back {
    height: 690px;
    background-position: center 20%;
  }

  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.333333%;
    margin-top: -1%;
  }

  div.bhoechie-tab-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 69%;
  }


    /* for home page */

  #home-2 .container-fluid {
    height: 690px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 650px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }   

    /*for project page */
  .pc {
    height: 550px;
    float: right;
  }

  .team-back3 {
    height: 690px;
    background-position: center 20%;
  }
} 

@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
    /* for about page */
  .team-right-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .team-back1 {
    height: 798px;
    background-position: 10% center;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

    /* for service page */
  .team-back {
    height: 798px;
    background-position: center -35%;
  }

  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 60.333333%;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }

  div.bhoechie-tab-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 76%;
  }


    /* for home page */

  #home-2 .container-fluid {
    height: 798px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 680px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }   

    /*for project page */
  .pc {
    height: 580px;
    float: right;
  }

  .team-back3 {
    height: 798px;
    background-position: center -35%;
  }


    /* for contact page */
  #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 798px;
  }

  .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 680px !important;
  }

  #map {
    height: 680px;
  }

  .contct-middle-back {
    height: 680px;
  }

  .contct-right-back {
    height: 680px;
  }

  .row {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
  .team-right-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

    /* for projects*/
  .team-back3 {
    height: 760px;
    background-position: 30% center;
  }

  .project-content {
    height: 512px;
  }

  .bret {
    width: 970px;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  .project-height {
    height: 512px;
    margin-top: -4%;
  }


    /* for about page */
  .team-back1 {
    height: 760px;
    background-position: 10% 20%;
  }

  .team-right-content {
    margin-top: -4%;
  } 

    /* for service page */
  .team-back {
    height: 760px;
    /* background-position: center -40%;   */
    background-position: 5% -10%;
  }

  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 60.333333%;
    margin-top: 4%;
  }

  div.bhoechie-tab-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 89%;
  }


    /* for home page */

  #home-2 .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;
  }

  [class*="cell-2"],
    .masonry .post-item {
    min-height: 700px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }   

    /*for project page */
  .pc {
    /* height: 600px; */
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* float: right;}  */
    /* for contact page */
    #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;
  }

  #contact-us .container-fluid {
    height: 760px;
  }

  .contct-lft-bck {
    height: 685px !important;
  }

  #map {
    height: 685px;
  }

  .contct-right-back {
    height: 685px;
  }

  .row {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
  }

  .contt {
    height: 760px!important;
  }
}
```

Also you had some left over curly brackets and some random styles. Also check every line of code properly there might be some errors in some lines involving brackets.

Comment: This might be able to work. Well for most part of it, it worked but still experiencing some issues with a query @ (min-width:1800;)

Comment: inside min-width :1800 px there is an error in .pc {} a bracket is missing there have you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with the closing of the queries and also some of the tags...

The some queries are "double closed", there is an additional `}` before the `@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px)` and `@media only screen and (max-width:1140px)` query.

Secondary within `@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px)` your `.pc` isn't closed.

A decent validator or even editor should have noticed this..